# Pandas, how to take the pd.Dataframe as a argument in functions

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Actually, to simplify the code, instead of writing two similar part codes, I decide to use a function with Dataframe as arguments. Like following:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

train_one = split_one
test_one = split_two
train_two = split_two
test_two = split_one

def train_predict(train_arg, predict_arg):
    knn = KNeighborsRegressor()
    knn.fit(train_arg['accommodates'], train_arg['price'])
    predict = knn.predict(predict_arg['accommodates'])
    rmse = numpy.sqrt(mean_squared_error(predict_arg['price'], predict))
    return rmse

iteration_one_rmse = train_predict(train_one, test_one)
iteration_two_rmse = train_predict(train_two, test_two)

avg_rmse = numpy.mean(iteration_one_rmse, iteration_two_rmse)
```

Maybe the arguments in the function definition block are inappropriate. However, I can not figure it out. Thanks for any hints.
With the error notice like that:

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f3f78fcf6758> in <module>()
     14     return rmse
     15 
---> 16 iteration_one_rmse = train_predict(train_one, test_one)
     17 iteration_two_rmse = train_predict(train_two, test_two)
     18 

<ipython-input-1-f3f78fcf6758> in train_predict(train_arg, predict_arg)
      9 def train_predict(train_arg, predict_arg):
     10     knn = KNeighborsRegressor()
---> 11     knn.fit(train_arg['accommodates'], train_arg['price'])
     12     predict = knn.predict(predict_arg['accommodates'])
     13     rmse = numpy.sqrt(mean_squared_error(predict_arg['price'], predict))

/dataquest/system/env/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.py in fit(self, X, y)
    739         """
    740         if not isinstance(X, (KDTree, BallTree)):
--> 741             X, y = check_X_y(X, y, "csr", multi_output=True)
    742         self._y = y
    743         return self._fit(X)

/dataquest/system/env/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    529         y = y.astype(np.float64)
    530 
--> 531     check_consistent_length(X, y)
    532 
    533     return X, y

/dataquest/system/env/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    179     if len(uniques) > 1:
    180         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 181                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    182 
    183 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 1862]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `train_arg` is a dataframe, then `train_arg['accomodates']` is a series whereas `train_arg[['accomodate']]` is a dataframe (containing only one column).

Since the data used in fit and predict is supposed to have multiple columns, the functions will on a `pandas.DataFrame` but not on a `pandas.Series`.

To prevent this error from happening, make sure your data (first argument in fit, and only argument in predict) is of `pandas.DataFrame` or `numpy.ndarray` type.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I modified the code like below.

```
def train_predict(train_arg, predict_arg):
    knn = KNeighborsRegressor()
    knn.fit(train_arg[['accommodates']], train_arg['price'])
    predict = knn.predict(predict_arg[['accommodates']])
    rmse = numpy.sqrt(mean_squared_error(predict_arg['price'], predict))
    return rmse
```

**Note the double brackets in** `train_arg[['accommodates']]`.

Adding the double brackets does work. But I did not understand the reason indeed. Any hints there?